# Загрузка файла в указанную папку

Tags: android, webview

У меня есть компонент `WebView`, который открывает мобильный сайт. Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку скачивание файла, открывалось простое файловое диалоговое окно, куда сохранить файл в устройстве.

Как можно это реализовать?

```
 mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
   public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
   String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
   long contentLength) {
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
   startActivity(i);
   }
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартного интента реализующего файловый менеджер/файловый диалог в Android'е нет. Так что единственный способ написать это самому (не так это сложно) или же взять готовый интент с исходниками и присобачить к своему коду. Например [пошукайте здесь](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/)